# Testing external API's using Angular 2 & Apache

Tags: apache, http, angular, cors

I am trying to make an HTTP requeset to an external API using the following request:

```
let headers = new Headers({
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"
  });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify({
test: test
      comments: "test"
     });
    this.http.post("EXTERNAL_API_URL", body, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

When I am making the API call from Chrome Postman plugin, the API works without any problem.

When I'm trying to make this call from my angular 2 app, the call is not working and returns the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load MY_API_URL. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know that I can access bypass it using the no web-security chrome:

```
Chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

But I wish to make it work without it...

I also tried to add   `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in my `http.conf` as described [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html).

Any ideas?

Comment: For that I use a proxy : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/889

Comment: Hey thanks, I created a proxy file with the following content: `{
  "/cc": {
    "target": "API_URL",
    "secure": true
  }
}`, but I get the same error. How does that work? IN my http.post I tried to set the URL to `/cc` and the orginal API url, both cause error

Comment: so if you send the "/cc" request, the proxy will answer with "API_URL/cc". Is it ?

Comment: @Karbos I get simply `POST http://localhost:4200/cc 404 (Not Found)` using `this.http.post("/cc", body, options)`

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work with you. You may read the doc : https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy or https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

Comment: does your proxy work now ?

Comment: Yeah I worked it out, I decided to create php backend for external API calls and I figured it out it's nearly impossible to call external API's directly from the browser. The proxy worked and can be good solution when you try to call your own api in localhost mode, but not for external API's.

Comment: Yes it's a good solution for developpement mode. In production you will have a reverse proxy like Apache or something else...